# Android create Listview using Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I am trying to create a dynamic listview, prior is used this in the onCreate Method inside my ArticleListFragment:

```
    JokeListAdapter jokeAdapter = new JokeListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(jokeAdapter);
```

That created me a ListView based on static items, now I am trying to create the ListViews based on the items of my api.

Currently I am running this with a successful response but I do not get any items in my listview it is still empty:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        call = service.jokes();
        call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Joke>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Joke> call, Response<Joke> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Joke> jokes = response.body();
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is successful");
                    setListAdapter(new JokeListAdapter(jokes));
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is successful");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is not successful");
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Joke> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response on failure");
            }
        });
}
```

This is my Adapter Constructor:

```
private class JokeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public JokeListAdapter(List<Joke> jokes) {
        Joke.ITEMS = jokes;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this,

```
private JokeListAdapter jokeListAdapter;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        jokeListAdapter = new JokeListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(jokeListAdapter);
        call = service.jokes();
        call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Joke>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Joke> call, Response<Joke> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<Joke> jokes = response.body();
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is successful");
                    jokeListAdapter.setValue(jokes);
                    //setListAdapter(new JokeListAdapter(jokes));
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is successful");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "response is not successful");
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Joke> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response on failure");
            }
        });
}
```

In JokeListAdapter.java change like this.

```
private class JokeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Joke> mJokes = new ArrayList<Joke>(); // use this list for every ever in adapter
    public JokeListAdapter() {

    }
    public void setValue(List<Joke> jokes) {
        mJokes.clear(); // Clearing old items(To add new items only)
        if(jokes != null && jokes.size() > 0) { // We dont need to add if the size is 0
             mJokes.addAll(jokes); // Adding all the item to the list item
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged(); // We are refreshing View the latest with list items.
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return mJokes.size();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer currently I get this errors `cannot resolve symbol jokeListAdapter` here `jokeListAdapter.setValue(jokes);`  invalid method `declaration return type required` here `public setValue(List<Joke> jokes) {`

Comment: **public void setValue(List<Joke> jokes)** not **public setValue(List<Joke> jokes)** my mistake i updated my answer.

Comment: Do you mind explaining further what the setValue method does also the notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Do you mind moving to chat I have an additional question, related to this one

Comment: Nop ask me, How can I help you..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151209/discussion-between-utdev-and-muthukrishnan-rajendran).

Comment: Hi again do you have time again, I could need some help :)